# Are JavaScript private fields private per class or per instance?

Tags: javascript, oop

JavaScript recently added private class fields, named with a hash prefix.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

I'm looking for a clear answer on whether this form of privacy is 'per class' or 'per instance.'

Say a Person class is defined with a private field named '#secret'.

I use 'new' to construct two instances of Person class: person1 and person2.

Does person1 have access to inspect and modify #secret field of person2?

```
class Person {
  #secret;
  constructor(secret) {
    this.#secret = secret;
  }
  getSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody) {
    return somebody.#secret;
  }
  setSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody, value) {
    somebody.#secret = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's right there in the MDN paged you linked: for a class field, the declaration includes the keyword `static`. Without that, they're instance fields. This is something you can easily demonstrate for yourself with a simple test program.

Comment: @pointy They are instance fields. This doesn't mean the privacy is enforced per instance.

Comment: "named with a hashtag prefix" - No, no, no, no, no, no, please no. [The `#` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) is correctly referred to as the _hash-symbol_ (or _number symbol_ or even "pound" for some strange Americans), but it is _never ever_ referred to as a "hashtag". The term "hashtag" came about from the repurposing of the hash-symbol "`#`" to denote a social taxonomic label. What you're doing is like referring to a wheelchair _as an_ accessible-toilet, or pointing at real-life 3.5-inch disks sold in Staples and declaring them _save-icons_...

Comment: From the Wikipedia article you cited, "the symbol itself is sometimes called a hashtag"

Comment: @ATOMP Yes, but my position is from the _prescriptivist_ school. Wikipedia is being objective and correct in mentioning that _other people_ do use the term "hashtag" to refer to the symbol, but the Wikipedia page itself does not authoritatively say that `#` is canonically or otherwise named "hashtag". I'm contending that people that _do_ use the neologism are more likely ignorant of the symbol's history rather than intentionally being descriptivist in their writing.

Answer (score 3):

They're per class - an instance can view and modify another instance.

```js
class Person {
  #secret;
  constructor(secret) {
    this.#secret = secret;
  }
  getSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody) {
    return somebody.#secret;
  }
  setSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody, value) {
    somebody.#secret = value;
  }
}

const a = new Person('a');
const b = new Person('b');
console.log(a.getSomebodyElsesSecret(b))
a.setSomebodyElsesSecret(b, 'c');
console.log(a.getSomebodyElsesSecret(b))
```

One way to look at it is that private fields are similar to variables scoped *only to the class* - they can be referenced however you want by anything inside the class's `{}`, and can't be referenced outside.

In terms of scope, it's a bit like a WeakMap that defines the private variables and an IIFE that returns the class:

```js
const Person = (() => {
    const secrets = new WeakMap();
    return class Person {
        constructor(secret) {
            secrets.set(this, secret);
        }
        getSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody) {
            return secrets.get(somebody);
        }
        setSomebodyElsesSecret(somebody, value) {
            secrets.set(somebody, value);
        }
    }
})();

const a = new Person('a');
const b = new Person('b');
console.log(a.getSomebodyElsesSecret(b))
a.setSomebodyElsesSecret(b, 'c');
console.log(a.getSomebodyElsesSecret(b))
```

Comment: Does JavaScript/ECMAScript have any _escape-hatches_ to allow for accessing those private-properties? I remember before private-properties were introduced there was a good number of people asking for a way to bypass the protections (a-la Reflection in Java and .NET) because inevitably someone is going to _need_ to, e.g. to work-around a bug in an external dependency, etc, but I didn't know how the conversation ended.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. Also, the WeakMap method above is the way they get transpiled by Babel (or at least quite similar), and there's no (decent) way to access the inside of a closure. All references must be strictly within the `class` that it's defined - not even subclasses or superclasses can reference others' private fields.

Comment: @Dai   Seen as JS is just text, you can always monkey patch.. Even maybe using a service worker to do the patching.. Wouldn't be pretty, but if a bug in a 3rd party lib caused major issues it's certainly an option..

Comment: @CertainPerformance I remember having to pass an application of `eval` into a higher-ordered function in order to fiddle with its closure that was otherwise completely inaccessible, that was fun...